# search form in nav bar doesn't render anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form  in my nav bar

```
  <%= simple_form_for :query, url: clients_products_path, method: :get,  wrapper: :inline_form, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.input  :keyword, placeholder: "Recherche" %>
    <%= f.submit "Valider" %>
  <% end %>
```

In my **product_controller.rb**

```
class Clients::ProductsController < ApplicationController


def index
  filter_products if params[:query].present?
  @products ||= Product.all
end

private

def filter_products
  return if params[:query].blank?
  @products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', params[:query][:keyword]) if params[:query][:keyword].present?
end
```

end

My query seems to be correct as I can find product in the rails console. 
but it doesn't display anything in the product#index...
Where am I wrong?

> update

All products are well displayed, and everything disapear when I make a query
**clients/products/index.html.erb**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= link_to clients_product_path(product) do  %>
        <%= image_tag(product.attachments.first.url) %>
        <%= product.title %>
        <%= product.price %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

here is the result

```
http://localhost:3000/clients/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query%5Bkeyword%5D=jean&commit=Valider
```

Comment: Please share the code of your `index` page where you are trying to display the values.

Comment: what do you get on index page when you don't have query params and what do you get with query params?

Comment: I get all my products when there are no query, and I get nothing at all with a query

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/clients/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query%5Bkeyword%5D=jean&commit=Valider`

Comment: <%= link_to clients_product_path(product) do  %> what u mean?

Comment: that link to wraps an image a price and a title.... when u click on the cart it recirect to the product show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue lies here:

```
@products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', params[:query][:keyword])
```

You need to either prepend, append or wrap your query with `%`. For example:

```
@products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:keyword]}%")
# Think it's the above, though could be the following:
# @products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE "%?%"', params[:query][:keyword])
```

If you have a read on SQL's `LIKE` operator, the `%` operates something like a wildcard. Without these, you're searching for an exact match, rather than a phrase contained within the title. [Docs are here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Give that a shot and let me know how you get on.

Comment: You're welcome, and great, glad to hear it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are checking `params[:query]` twice(once when calling `filter_products` and second time in that function)

And their is something wrong with you `filter_products` function.

When you do `@products ||= Product.all` you get blank `ActiveRecordRelation` if query returns empty relation. In other words `@products` will always be blank if `query[:keyword]` doesn't match the `title`.

Try changing your index function to:

```
def index
  @products = Product.where('lower(title) LIKE %?%', params[:query][:keyword].downcase) if params[:query][:keyword].present?
  puts @products
  @products ||= Product.all
end
```

If it still returns blank, then try to print `@products` variable.

Comment: tanks for your suggestion, yes you are right i was checking this twice, but that finally wasn't the problem :)  thanks anyway